# How to display html source code with proper tag color style and indentation as in Editors

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I want to show source code of html file rendered in iframe. Source code must be display with proper tag colors and indentations as in editors like sublime.
[image: expected result]
I got source code of file rendered in iframe with

```
    var sourceCode = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n\<html lang="en-US">\n';
    sourceCode  += $('#iFrame').contents().find("html").html();
    sourceCode += '\n</html>';
    sourceCode = sourceCode.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    sourceCode = "<pre>"+sourceCode+"</pre>";
```

but this gives me a pre-formated text as [image: my result]
How can i do this.

Answer (score 1):

Create a gist on github and just embed it?